# How to check if a value in an array is a certain number greater than a value in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

Say I have 2 arrays like this:`let x = [1,3,4,7,10]` and another array like this `let y = [0,4,6,9,12]`
How would I check if there's any value in the arrays separated by a 1? For example, 3 from the first array, and 4 from the second array. These are separated by one, so it returns true. I'm looking for it to return a boolean value. To clear up any doubts, the Array IS sorted but not always the same length or sometimes even empty, and the other values also count, I just used one of the values.

Comment: what about `1` and `0`? are the arrays always sorted?

Comment: and what about `6` and `7`? is the index relevant?

Comment: Not really, I was looking for it to return a boolean value to be returned to answer Thomas's question.

Comment: The arrays are always sorted with ascending values, and sometimes one of the arrays can be empty, and they don't always have the same length.

Answer (score 3):

This approach iterates both arrays but needs sorted arrays.

On iterating it takes the smaller values first, despite of the array.

If two values are found who have a delta of one, the function `check` returns `true` otherwise `false`.

```js
function check(a, b) {
    let i = 0,
        j = 0;
        
    do {
        console.log(a[i], b[j]);
        if (a[i] + 1 === b[j] || a[i] === b[j] + 1) return true;
        if (a[i] <= b[j] && i + 1 < a.length) i++;
        else j++;
    } while (j < b.length) 
    return false;
}

console.log(check([1, 3, 4, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6, 9, 12])); // true
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 9, 12, 13, 14])); // true
console.log(check([6, 9, 12, 13, 14], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // true

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 9, 12, 13, 14])); // false
console.log(check([7, 9, 12, 13, 14], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // false

console.log(check([3, 4], [3]));
console.log(check([3], [3, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: There's a failing edge case when `a[i] === b[b.length-1]` like `console.log(check([3, 4], [3]))` this should return `true`. But it increments `j` and ends the loop. Solution: `if(a[i] < b[j] || a[i] === b[j] && (a.length-i) > (b.length-j)) i++;` if values are equal, increment the index that has more items left.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is

1. Eliminate all duplicates in both arrays (not worth it if you're iterating over small arrays)
2. For each item of the first array check if there is an item in the second array, whose value's absolute difference from the item selected from the first array is 1.
3. If there is such an item, you straight away return `true`
4. If no items follow those conditions, return `false`

An implementation of that in JS should look something like that:

```js
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
    return arr.filter((v, i) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
    // Removes every single item that has a different indexOf index than its own
    // This is a clever technique i found on https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c
}

function anyItemsWithDiffrence1(arr1, arr2, eliminateDuplicates) {
    if (eliminateDuplicates) {
        arr1 = eliminateDuplicates(arr1);
        arr2 = eliminateDuplicates(arr2);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) === 1) return true;
            // We check if the absolute difference between the two items is 1
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you mistyped arr[2] instead of arr[j] :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry.